# Web-based CMS for mobile app

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, mobile, responsive-webdesign

I'm just about to start developing a mobile app which needs to be fed from a CMS. I started designing the tables when I thought there must be something out there which could save me a load of time and let me concentrate on the mobile side of things.

So, I'm looking for a CMS that will let me create hierarchical "pages" which will just be 4-5 database fields with a simple front-end to allow to edit and update them. I don't mind having to write some code to layout the database and forms etc, any saving on starting from scratch would be good. The only requirement is that I be able to access the data via some sort of web service, REST, JSON, XML, anything really...

Can anyone suggest anything that might help?

Thanks,
J

Comment: A "mobile app" can be many different things. If you can't provide details, I doubt you will get useful answers. Can you further explain the 4-5 database fields?

Comment: Most CMS's will do this thought responsive design...

Answer (score 0):

First of all [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) can help you to design mobile based apps.

Further, if you are looking for a CMS, I had tried wordpress with some special plugins who optimize your blog/site as per the device (mobile/pad) automatically. And it works perfect.